# Different errors occurs in every compilation

Tags: mysql, vb.net

What is the reason why I get different types of error in every-time I execute my program?

I am trying to fetch data from MySql and transfer it to MsAccess.
While fetching, my program also do insertion to MsAccess with the data that is fetched from MySql.
These are the errors:
'Fatal error encountered during command execution'
'Probable I/O race condition detected while copying memory. The I/O package is not thread safe by default. In multithreaded applications, a stream must be accessed in a thread-safe way, such as a thread-safe wrapper returned by TextReader's or TextWriter's Synchronized methods. This also applies to classes like StreamWriter and StreamReader.'

```vb
Dim query As String
Dim query2 As String
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
Dim dt As New DataTable
For i As Integer = 0 To Dgvstoreinvoice.Rows.Count - 1
    query = "SELECT * FROM hct_info_cap_order_sub_lotnumber WHERE hct_id_invoice = '" & Dgvstoreinvoice.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & "'"
    Dim data As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn)
    data.Fill(dt) '- The errors occurs here
    data.Dispose()
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        query2 = "INSERT INTO [Ship-out Details]([InvoiceID],[Ship-outID],[Lot No],[Qty],[No of tray],[Packing No],[Carton no],[Type]) " & _
                               "VALUES(@InvoiceID,@ShipdusoutID,@Lot_No,@Qty,@No_of_tray,@Packing_No,@Carton_no,@type)"
        For o As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            updatelabel(lblLoadingMsg1, "[Save Data] of " & dt.Rows(o)("hct_lotnumber"))
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(query2, oledb_conn2)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceID", dt.Rows(o)("hct_id_invoice"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShipdusoutID", dt.Rows(o)("hct_cap_order_sub_id"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lot_No", dt.Rows(o)("hct_lotnumber"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", dt.Rows(o)("hct_qty"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@No_of_tray", dt.Rows(o)("hct_noofTray"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Packing_No", dt.Rows(o)("hct_packingNO"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Carton_no", dt.Rows(o)("hct_cartonNO"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", dt.Rows(o)("hct_type"))
            oleopen_(oledb_conn2)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            oleclose_(oledb_conn2)
            'saveShip_out_details(dt.Rows(o)("hct_id_invoice"), dt.Rows(o)("hct_cap_order_sub_id"), dt.Rows(o)("hct_lotnumber"), dt.Rows(o)("hct_qty"), _
            '                     dt.Rows(o)("hct_noofTray"), dt.Rows(o)("hct_packingNO"), dt.Rows(o)("hct_cartonNO"), dt.Rows(o)("hct_type"))
            Dim rows As New DataGridViewRow
            rows.Cells.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxCell With {.Value = dt.Rows(o)("hct_cap_order_sub_id")})
            delegate_row_add(Dgvforpodetails, rows)
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Based on the error messages, you're executing code in multiple threads at the same time.  The types/code you're using to do that are not thread-safe, hence the error messages.  The actions in different threads don;t always execute in the same sequence, hence the different error messages each time.  As suggested, if you want specific help with specific code then you need to provide that code.  Please take the time to do some reading in the Help centre for this site to learn how to ask a good question and avoid asking bad questions.

Comment: I already update my question Master's, thank you for giving your time helping me in fixing this problem.

Comment: It's not clear how/when/from where this code is called. Also, where that DataTable (`dt`) is defined and what is using it. What defines/creates/uses the connection and when this happens is also unclear. If you're threding this code as it appears to be, don't.

Comment: You could make your life a lot easier by having the MySQL select rows into a datatable using AS to alias the column names into being what they would be for the access db, then use another data adapter to insert the rows to access (use a command builder to generate you an insert query, or create a typed dataset/table for the access side of things) - the only thing you'd need is a loop to iterate the table and set the rowstate to New so the insert is called. That datatable should be databoibd to your grid, not poking the datagridview cell values directly

Comment: @CaiusJard, that loop would be unnecessary.  You simply set the `AcceptChangesOnFill` property of the data adapter to `False`.  The `Fill` method has to create new rows in the first place, so they are all `Added` by default.  A call to `AcceptChanges` then makes them `Unchanged`  Using that property, you can exclude that call and they remain `Added`, ready for insert.

Comment: @jmcilhinney that's a good tip, thanks! Hi, by the way, used to see you a lot on VBDNF - JohnH still around?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, you're apparently making this way harder than it needs to be.  Copying data from one database to another is really just a `Fill` call on one data adapter and an `Update` call on another.  If your column names match up, you can use a command builder but, if they don't, you can just write the `INSERT` statement yourself.  Here are a couple of examples.

Unmatched columns:

```vb
Dim sourceAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM SomeTable", "source connection string here")
Dim table As New DataTable

sourceAdapter.Fill(table)

Dim destinationConnection As New OleDbConnection("destination connection string here")
Dim destinationCommand As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO SomeOtherTable (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES (@ColumnA, @ColumnB)", destinationConnection)

With destinationCommand.Parameters
    .Add("@ColumnA", OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "Column1")
    .Add("@ColumnB", OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "Column2")
End With

Dim destinationAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter With {.InsertCommand = destinationCommand}

destinationAdapter.Update(table)
```

Matched columns:

```vb
Dim sourceAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Column1 AS ColumnA, Column2 AS ColumnB FROM SomeTable", "source connection string here")
Dim table As New DataTable

sourceAdapter.Fill(table)

Dim destinationAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB FROM SomeOtherTable", "destination connection string here")
Dim destinationBuilder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(destinationAdapter)

destinationAdapter.Update(table)
```

Comment: Small typo in the source data adapter type; sql vs mysql

Comment: That wasn't actually a typo.  I just used `SqlClient` in the example code I wrote because it's available by default.  The same principles hold regardless of the source and destination providers, so I didn't bother trying to match.  In fact, you could even use `OleDb` for both the source and the destination and use a single data adapter, if you weren't using a command builder.  There's no requirement to use the same connection for the `SelectCommand` and the `InsertCommand`.

Comment: True, I'm just concerned that the OP will copy it literally, paste, edit a few bits (but not change that) and hit a problem because it's the SqlServer targeted adapter on a MySQL db; could be a hard thing to find

Comment: Fair call.  Examples should be treated as examples but they often aren't.

Comment: I think especially on SO - I mean, everyone knows that once a question with a bit of code is asked, the algorithmic problem is handed off to someone else to write, right? :) it's like freelancer.com, except actually free!